# how to programmatically enable remote management under sharing in Mac OS X 10.8

Tags: objective-c, macos, applescript, core-services, remote-management

I am working on a project which requires VNC Server to be run on my system (Mac OS X v10.8).

VNS server is installed in my Mac system, now I need to run VNC server, but for running the server sufficient privileges needs to be provided programmatically or using Apple Script(System Preference -> Sharing -> Remote Management -> Enable the check box).

How could I enable remote management through objective c program or apple script ?
or is there any API provided by Apple to manage sharing options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable and configure the remote management service with the `kickstart` command. It's not in the usual PATH, so you need to specify its full path:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart
```

Its option format is a little cryptic, but with some experimentation you should be able to get the effect you want (see [Apple's KB #HT2370](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2370) and [SS64.com's "man page"](http://ss64.com/osx/kickstart.html)).

Also, it must run as root, so from AppleScript, use `do shell script with administrator privileges`. I think you'll need something close to this:

```
do shell script "/System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -activate -configure -access -on -restart -agent -privs -all" with administrator privileges
```